# How are client side Session Ids protected?

Tags: php, session

What keeps someone from logging in to web-site Z.  Going into the cookie holding the Session_Id for web-site Z, and fiddling with it to becomes someone else as identified by the server?

Comment: You are responsive for making the session id safe, e.g. hashing the id and an identifier to be controlled each request by the server.

Comment: If someone can log into your server, you have bigger problems than session protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing but the length and base of session ids.  If it is quite long it would take trillions (or more) tries before a collision is found.  Longer ids multiply the number of possible ids by the base of the hash, so if your hash has numbers and lowercase letters, every extra character multiplies the possibilities by 36.

A 20 character hash will give you 36^20 different possibilities.  If you double the length of the id, you get 36^40 different possibilities.  Making it much harder for anyone to brute force into another account.

Comment: What hash do PHP sessions use when storing an identifier?  What is there algorithm...I'm no hack..I just want to use the same algorithm to manually to create my own session_ids?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist By default it uses md5, but that is configurable in a php.ini and there are better hashes you can use

Comment: Better Hashes - Can you respond here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905930/what-hash-do-php-sessions-use-when-storing-an-id

Answer (score 2):

> What keeps someone from logging in to web-site Z. Going into the cookie holding the Session_Id for web-site Z, and fiddling with it to becomes someone else as identified by the server?

You would have to actually *know* another session ID to do this. Session IDs are very long and random on purpose, so you can't guess another user's ID.

Answer (score 1):

If we talk about php session, the answer is "no one protect them" !

You have to do something for try to make it "more secure".

- Use SSL for authentication
- Make session id expire over the time
- Check IP and USER AGENT (ok, that could be circumvented)

and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

In some cases (CodeIgniter framework) you can encrypt your cookies which makes this attack that much more difficult.

Ultimately you as the developer are responsible for security, nothing is out of the box, its just a matter of following proper security guidelines for developing safe apps.