# What hash do PHP sessions use when storing an id?

Tags: php, session

What is the algorithm.  I would like to use the same algorithm to manually create my own session_ids which I want to store locally as well.

I realize I could create it server side ( using session functions ) and send it...but I just prefer to hash / encode it myself...+ I want the option to increase the complexity to my liking...fiddle with it etc.

Related:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835592/how-are-client-side-session-ids-protected)

Thanks.

Comment: *"cryptographically broken"* - I'd argue PHP's implementation of md5 in its session functionality was more geared towards uniqueness and not security. I've never heard about md5 creating duplicate session ids.

Comment: MD5 is cryptographically broken per en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: Per the answer it is default not a choice on my part...I was not aware that it was not secure...till recently...I'm going to use SHA-512...with random salt generation for my needs.

Comment: The user identifier on the client is just as important as the email/pass combo b.c. if it is hacked...the hacker has access to the account....that is what I'm going to user it for...this I'm told is the weakest link in security...client-side identification.

Comment: I can't cover all of that right now...basics first...but thanks...great info...I'll return to it later if needed..but that method you elaborated on I would say is one of the easiest most basic hacks possible...if someone did use un-salted md5...using rainbow tables per below.

Comment: I don't have any interests in learning how to hack ( so I can't tell you step by step) but it is clear this is a vulnerability.  Answer Below.  I'm sure there is an entire academic sub-field focused on making better hashes - here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2.  The progression seems to be SHA-1, SHA-2, SHA-3.

Comment: Hiro what does a better hash mean to you? It seems like you're taking that for face-value. "It's a better hash therefore I need to be using it for everything". The answer below doesn't show how md5 is making your sessions vulnerable. Just another comment about it being old. Also, securing your code doesn't make you a hacker. Securing your code means learning how hackers work and preventing their attempts. Please convey to me why you think you're sessions are vulnerable due to md5.

Comment: Rainbow table reverse lookup...If you know the actual ID using this...then you can just change it...and you become another user to the server...I'm not worried about this right now...as I'm just prototyping...I just prefer to use a hash with both uniqueness and security...2 birds with one stone.

Comment: Also like the fact that SHA-X and AES ( I use this for 2-way ) are NSA approved technologies...lot of effort went into creating them

Comment: @MikeB If you new that was the hashing algorithm then you could find out the time that another users session started to say within one second (1000 possible value) by triggering their session start within an iframe on your own domain and tracking the time. Then you only have to guess the random value which might give you 1000*2^32 which is a bit less than 2^42. So instead of having to guess from 2^128 hash values when brute forcing you only have to guess from 2^42 possible values. A huge security vulnerability. Fortunately PHP's hash algorithm also contains the users IP so you need that too.

Comment: @MikeB Of course if you got them to visit your own site and hit the server in an iframe you have their IP as well, but PHP has increased the security in their session generation algorithm since PHP 5.3.3 because of attacks like this: http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2010/Mar/519

Comment: @MikeB md5 has 128 output bits. If it was perfectly secure, which it isn't, it would take 2^127 attempts to brute force it on average (half the possible values). An algorithm that outputs 1 additional bit takes twice as long to brute force (SHA-1 outputs 160 bits so it takes much longer). SHA-512 outputs 512 bits which is ridiculous with our current processing power but eventually it will become weak too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP uses md5 by default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.hash-function), but can be configured to use sha-1 and as of PHP 5.3 many other [hashing algorithms](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php).

You can choose your own algorithm, but it should be at least as strong as md5 and probably should be stronger as md5 is getting a bit out of date.

Comment: A bit off topic but is a hash one way or two way...can I go back to the original data if I have the hash and of course the algorithm?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist A hash, by design, is one-way. It should not be possible to get the original data back if all you have is the hash. (But the reason MD5 is no longer recommended for secure use is because this is increasingly possible to do with MD5.)

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Hashing is irreversible and more. A secure cryptographic hash function has the property that it is hard to find to different sets of input that hash to the same thing.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist An unsalted hash may be reversible using Rainbow tables. So you should always salt your hashes.

Comment: @MikeB It depends on the algorithm for generating session ids, if it's something like an auto incrementing integer that is being hashed you want that salted, because if someone can recover the integer used to generate a single they'd be able to generate any session id they want. I'm sure you know that though so I'm really just saying it for the sake of any other reader. Also hashed auto incrementing numbers aren't a good way to generate session ids, it's just an example.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. If it were hashing an auto incremented key wouldn't every PHP application be extremely vulnerable? Again, the primary function of the algorithm used to generate the hash is uniqueness, not security. Using the session_id as your security mechanism is the wrong way to do things.

Comment: @MikeB Well the OP is talking about writing his own algorithm for generating his own session id's, not the algorithm that is used by default in PHP. If he chooses to hash incrementing numbers to generate the id's then he better salt them or there will be a security vulnerability.

Comment: @Paul - I think random function seeded with time used as a salt for SHA-512 is un-hackable well into the future....for a certain sub-set of hacks / attacks...thanks for the info.